# Sending response to ipcRenderer from ipcMain after asynchronous operation completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, electron, fast-csv

I'm learning Electron by writing the app that should parse and analyze .csv files. As a frontend part of it I'm using Vue.js. Initial functionality should be next: user selects a file, main process parses it, file's summary displayed at the client as a part of a Vue component. Code below:

```
//background.js
import Analyzer from './Analyzer'
analyzer = new Analyzer();

ipcMain.on('data:upload', (event, data) => {
    let options = {
      filters: [{ 
        extensions: ['csv']
      }] 
    };
    let filepath = dialog.showOpenDialog(options);
    analyzer.loadDataCSV(filepath);  //executes async code
    event.sender.send('data:upload', analyzer.getState());// doesn't wait
})                                                        // async code to be completed 
                                                          // so the 'state' I'm sending 
                                                          // is actually incorrect


//Analyzer.js - class that i've wrote
import csv from 'fast-csv'
...
loadDataCSV(filepath) {
    if (!filepath) return;
    this.dataWSFilepath = filepath;
    this.showDataCard = true;
    let rowsCount = 0;
    csv. //async part
        fromPath(filepath, { delimiter: "|" })
        .on("data", function (data) {
            if (data[9] == 'NCR') rowsCount++;
        })
        .on("end", function () {
            this.NCRCount = rowsCount //Variable I'm expecting to be 
                                      //changed inside the Vue component
        });
}
getState(){ return { NCRCount: this.NCRCount }}
...
```

Please tell me the right way to wait the async part of loadDataCSV() to be completed before sending answer to ipcRenderer.